# OpenGL blending wall not drawn

Tags: c++, opengl, blending

I have problem with blendng in my opengl program
[image]

I know its because red wall was drawn before blue wall, but here is my question did i must check what wall is closer to camera or it is faster way to do this.

If i turn off deph testing have problem like this
[image]
Yellow wall was drawn before red

Comment: For this example it's probably sufficient to just turn off depth testing

Comment: Use an alpha mask instead of blending (e.g. alpha pass/fail). Then the depth buffer will still be beneficial. Now, since alpha testing was removed from GL 3.1, you will have to implement this in a fragment shader using `discard` unless you have a compatibility context.